# Javascript getAttribute in Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to load videos after the page finishes loading. The script I'm using works in firefox and chrome, but throws errors in Edge/IE.
the error is SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'append' of undefined or null reference I get it on the full build and the line it indicates is iframe.id = v[n].getAttribute('youtube'); The issue is that it doesn't add the iframe to the page so no videos. The error on codepen is Unable to get property 'src' of undefined or null reference since the iframe is not getting appended to the page. Here is the html/js I'm currently using. I've tried a few variations like v[n].attr(). I tried changing it to data-youtube and using v[n].dataset.youtube. Nothing seems to work in Edge.

[codepen working on ff/chrome](https://codepen.io/1bladesforhire/pen/eyGEar)

```
<section data-grid="container stack-2" class="m-multi-feature f-align-center" id="m-multi-tiles">
<section data-grid="container">
    <ul role="tablist">
        <li class="c-glyph" role="presentation">
                <a href="#" role="tab" class="c-logo" itemprop="url" aria-label="Item 13" aria-controls="newIconItemImage13 newIconItemContent13">
<span>Skyworld</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        <li class="c-glyph" role="presentation">
                <a href="#" role="tab" class="c-logo " itemprop="url" aria-label="Item 11" aria-controls="newIconItemImage11 newIconItemContent11">

                <span>SteamVR</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="c-glyph" role="presentation">
            <a href="#" role="tab" class="c-logo " itemprop="url" aria-label="Item 12" aria-controls="newIconItemImage12 newIconItemContent12">

                <span>SUPERHOT VR</span>
            </a>
        </li>           
        <li class="c-glyph" role="presentation">
            <a href="#" role="tab" class="c-logo" itemprop="url" aria-label="Item 14" aria-controls="newIconItemImage14 newIconItemContent14">

                <span>Free the Night</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="c-glyph" role="presentation">
            <a href="#" role="tab" class="c-logo" itemprop="url" aria-label="Item 15" aria-controls="newIconItemImage15 newIconItemContent15">

                <span>Minecraft</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="m-multi-description">
        <li id="newIconItemContent13" role="tabpanel" class="f-active">
            <h4 class="c-heading-10">VERTIGO GAMES</h4>
                <h3 class="c-heading">Skyworld</h3>
                <p class="c-paragraph">Manage your economy, build and lead royal armies, rule dragons to restore your kingdom to glory. Battle the forces of evil as you conquer and reunite all Skyworlds in this turn-based strategy game that brings the beloved gameplay of strategy classics to VR.</p>
            </li>
        <li id="newIconItemContent11" role="tabpanel" >
            <!-- <h4 class="c-heading-10">Microsoft</h4> -->
            <h3 class="c-heading">Steam®VR</h3>
            <p class="c-paragraph">Dive into many of the most popular VR games available today. Experience more than 2,000 titles from the Steam®VR library on Windows Mixed Reality.<sup>11</sup></p>
        </li>
        <li id="newIconItemContent12" role="tabpanel">
            <h4 class="c-heading-10">SUPERHOT TEAM</h4>
            <h3 class="c-heading">SUPERHOT VR</h3>
            <p>
            The iconic VR FPS is here; time moves only when you do.
            </p>
        </li>

        <li id="newIconItemContent14" role="tabpanel">
            <h4 class="c-heading-10">JAUNT</h4>   
            <h3 class="c-heading">Free the Night</h3>
            <p class="c-paragraph">A magical interactive VR journey that invites you to blow out city lights and return the stars back into the night sky.</p>
        </li>
        <li id="newIconItemContent15" role="tabpanel">
            <h4 class="c-heading-10">MICROSOFT</h4>
            <h3 class="c-heading">Minecraft</h3>
            <p class="c-paragraph">Get right inside the world of Minecraft with mixed reality. Build, explore and battle mobs - do all the things you know and love - but from a fresh perspective.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="c-carousel f-multi-slide" role="region" aria-label="Images">
        <div class="background-skew"></div>
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
            <ul>
                <li id="newIconItemImage13" data-f-theme="dark" role="tabpanel" class="f-active">
                        <picture class="c-image">
                            <source srcset="assets/video/skyworld.jpg" media="(min-width: 1779px)">
                            <source srcset="assets/video/skyworld.jpg" media="(min-width:1400px)">
                            <source srcset="assets/video/skyworld.jpg" media="(min-width:1084px)">
                            <source srcset="assets/video/skyworld.jpg" media="(min-width:768px)">
                            <source srcset="assets/video/skyworld.jpg" media="(min-width:540px)">
                            <source srcset="assets/video/skyworld.jpg" media="(min-width:0)">
                            <img srcset="assets/video/skyworld.jpg" src="assets/video/skyworld.jpg" alt="Placeholder with grey background and dimension watermark without any imagery">
                        </picture>
                        <a class="c-glyph glyph-play playme" onclick="revealVideo('video3','youtube3')"></a>
                    </li>
                    <div id="video3" class="lightbox" onclick="hideVideo('video3','youtube3')">
                        <div class="lightbox-container">  
                            <div class="lightbox-content">


                                <div class="video-container  youtube-player" data-id="SN20mKCMEe8" youtube="youtube3">
                                    <!-- <iframe id="youtube3" width="960" height="540" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SN20mKCMEe8?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
                                </div>      

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button onclick="hideVideo('video3','youtube3')" class="lightbox-close c-glyph glyph-cancel">
                                </button>
                    </div>
                <li id="newIconItemImage11" data-f-theme="light"  role="tabpanel">
                    <picture class="c-image">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/steam-vr-1600.jpg" media="(min-width: 1779px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/steam-vr-1600.jpg" media="(min-width:1400px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/steam-vr-1600.jpg" media="(min-width:1084px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/steam-vr-1600.jpg" media="(min-width:768px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/steam-vr-1600.jpg" media="(min-width:540px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/steam-vr-1600.jpg" media="(min-width:0)">
                        <img srcset="assets/video/steam-vr-1600.jpg" src="assets/video/steam-vr-1600.jpg" alt="Placeholder with grey background and dimension watermark without any imagery">
                    </picture>
                    <a class="c-glyph glyph-play playme" onclick="revealVideo('video','youtube')"></a>
                </li>
                <div id="video" class="lightbox" onclick="hideVideo('video','youtube')">
                        <div class="lightbox-container">  
                            <div class="lightbox-content">


                                <div class="video-container  youtube-player" data-id="dXOVk5SNBRU" youtube="youtube">
                                    <!-- <iframe id="youtube" width="960" height="540" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dXOVk5SNBRU?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
                                </div>      

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button onclick="hideVideo('video','youtube')" class="lightbox-close c-glyph glyph-cancel">

                                </button>
                    </div>
                <li id="newIconItemImage12" data-f-theme="light"  role="tabpanel">
                    <picture class="c-image">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/superhot-1600.jpg" media="(min-width: 1779px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/superhot-1600.jpg" media="(min-width:1400px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/superhot-1600.jpg" media="(min-width:1084px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/superhot-1600.jpg" media="(min-width:768px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/superhot-1600.jpg" media="(min-width:540px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/superhot-1600.jpg" media="(min-width:0)">
                        <img srcset="assets/video/superhot-1600.jpg" src="assets/video/superhot-1600.jpg" alt="Placeholder with grey background and dimension watermark without any imagery">
                    </picture>
                        <a class="c-glyph glyph-play playme" onclick="revealVideo('video2','youtube2')"></a>
                </li>

                <div id="video2" class="lightbox" onclick="hideVideo('video2','youtube2')">
                        <div class="lightbox-container">  
                            <div class="lightbox-content">


                                <div class="video-container  youtube-player" data-id="A1jothqmqHw" youtube="youtube2">
                                    <!-- <iframe id="youtube2" width="960" height="540" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A1jothqmqHw?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
                                </div>      

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button onclick="hideVideo('video2','youtube2')" class="lightbox-close c-glyph glyph-cancel">

                                </button>
                    </div>


                <li id="newIconItemImage14" dat1a-f-theme="dark" role="tabpanel">
                <picture class="c-image">
                    <source srcset="assets/video/free-the-night.jpg" media="(min-width: 1779px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/free-the-night.jpg" media="(min-width:1400px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/free-the-night.jpg" media="(min-width:1084px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/free-the-night.jpg" media="(min-width:768px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/free-the-night.jpg" media="(min-width:540px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/free-the-night.jpg" media="(min-width:0)">
                        <img srcset="assets/video/free-the-night.jpg" src="assets/video/free-the-night.jpg" alt="Placeholder with grey background and dimension watermark without any imagery">
                    </picture>
                    <a class="c-glyph glyph-play playme" onclick="revealVideo('video4','youtube4')"></a>
                </li>
                <div id="video4" class="lightbox" onclick="hideVideo('video4','youtube4')">
                    <div class="lightbox-container">  
                        <div class="lightbox-content">


                            <div class="video-container  youtube-player" data-id="tlKQJcH0mgY" youtube="youtube4">
                                <!-- <iframe id="youtube4" width="960" height="540" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tlKQJcH0mgY?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
                            </div>      

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button onclick="hideVideo('video4','youtube4')" class="lightbox-close c-glyph glyph-cancel">
                            </button>
                </div>
                <li id="newIconItemImage15" dat1a-f-theme="dark" role="tabpanel">
                    <picture class="c-image">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/minecraft-thumb.jpg" media="(min-width: 1779px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/minecraft-thumb-1259.jpg" media="(min-width:1400px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/minecraft-thumb-1259.jpg" media="(min-width:1084px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/minecraft-thumb-1259.jpg" media="(min-width:768px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/minecraft-thumb-1259.jpg" media="(min-width:540px)">
                        <source srcset="assets/video/minecraft-thumb-1259.jpg" media="(min-width:0)">
                        <img srcset="assets/video/minecraft-thumb-1259.jpg" src="assets/video/minecraft-thumb-1259.jpg" alt="Placeholder with grey background and dimension watermark without any imagery">
                    </picture>
                    <a class="c-glyph glyph-play playme" onclick="revealVideo('video5','youtube5')"></a>
                </li>
                <div id="video5" class="lightbox" onclick="hideVideo('video5','youtube5')">
                    <div class="lightbox-container">  
                        <div class="lightbox-content">


                            <div class="video-container  youtube-player" data-id="dXOVk5SNBRU" youtube="youtube5">
                                <!-- <iframe id="youtube5" width="960" height="540" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dXOVk5SNBRU?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
                            </div>      

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button onclick="hideVideo('video5','youtube5')" class="lightbox-close c-glyph glyph-cancel">
                            </button>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
 //lazy load youtube vids
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
    function() {
        var div, n,
            v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
        for (n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            var embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?showinfo=0";
            iframe.setAttribute("src", embed.replace("ID", v[n].dataset.id));
            iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
            iframe.id = v[n].attributes['youtube'].value;
            v[n].append(iframe);
          console.log(v[n].getAttribute('youtube') + 'youtube');
        }
    });


// Function to reveal lightbox and add YouTube autoplay
function revealVideo(div, video_id) {
    var video = document.getElementById(video_id).src;
    document.getElementById(video_id).src = video + '&autoplay=1'; // adding autoplay to the URL
    document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
}

// Hiding the lightbox and removing YouTube autoplay
function hideVideo(div, video_id) {
    var video = document.getElementById(video_id).src;
    var cleaned = video.replace('&autoplay=1', ''); // removing autoplay form url
    document.getElementById(video_id).src = cleaned;
    document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: It seems impossible with the code you posted: `v[n].append` if `v[n]` is undefined then the previous line should have an error: `v[n].attributes`

Comment: v[n].getAttribute('youtube') isn't undefined in ff/chrome, but with edge it doesn't read the attribute for some reason. You can use the codepen link to see the working code and error on edge.

Comment: Your question states: `Unable to get property 'append' of undefined or null reference` If that's the error than the only code using `append` is `v[n].append` and if `v[n]` is undefined than the code you posted with the error you are getting is impossible because before that line you have `v[n].attributes` which would throw if `v[n]` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work by using  iframe.setAttribute('id', v[n].getAttribute('youtube')); not sure why this works and not v[n].attributes['youtube'].value;

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
    function() {
        var div, n,
            v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
        for (n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            var embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?showinfo=0";
            iframe.setAttribute("src", embed.replace("ID", v[n].dataset.id));
            iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
            iframe.setAttribute('id', v[n].getAttribute('youtube'));
            v[n].appendChild(iframe);
        }
    });
```